# Java 8 lambda expression evaluation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method similar to the following one:

```
public double[] foo(double[] doubleArray) { 
    DoubleStream stream = Arrays.stream(doubleArray);

    return stream.map(s -> s / stream.sum()).toArray();
}
```

What is the complexity of this method? How many times will `DoubleStream`'s `sum` method be executed? Once or `O(n)` times, with `n = doubleArray.length`?

Comment: this will still fail... you need to create the stream again from the source

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code will throw an exception, since you can't consume the same Stream more than once. You can only execute one terminal operation on a Stream.

If you change the code to:

```
public double[] foo(double[] doubleArray) { 
    return Arrays.stream(doubleArray).map(s -> s / Arrays.stream(doubleArray).sum()).toArray();
}
```

it will work, but the running time will be quadratic (`O(n^2)`), since the sum will be computed `n` times.

A better approach would be to compute the sum just once:

```
public double[] foo(double[] doubleArray) { 
    double sum = Arrays.stream(doubleArray).sum();
    return Arrays.stream(doubleArray).map(s -> s / sum).toArray();
}
```

This will run in linear time.

Comment: @Eugene You can mention it, or you can just write `linear time` as I did. It doesn't matter if it's n or 2n or cn. All are linear time.